# Is this a safe way to store my passwords?

Tags: php, security, encryption, hash, passwords

I've been reading around a few different guides/tutorials on this topic and found the following:

- [Storing Passwords Securely using Salt in PHP](http://www.opensecuritylab.org/storing-passwords-securely-using-salt-in-php)
- [Secure Hash and Salt for PHP Passwords (Top Answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords/401684#401684)

I know that what I've read there is a very secure way to store a users password. I've made an attempt to combined the 2 slightly while instead of using `mt_rand` like in the first example, I've generated my own dynamic salt.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    $static_salt = ""; // Removed value for obvious reasons

    $dynamic_salt_choice = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $dynamic_salt_length = 40;

    $dynamic_salt = "";

    $dynamic_salt_max = strlen($dynamic_salt_choice)-1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $dynamic_salt_length; $i++) {

        $dynamic_salt .= substr($dynamic_salt_choice, rand(0, $dynamic_salt_max), 1);

    }

    $password_length = length($password);
    $split_at = $password_length / 2;
    $password_array = str_split($password, $split_at);

    $password = $password_array[0] . $static_salt . $password_array[1];

    $password_hash = hash_hmac('sha512', $password, $dynamic_salt);

?>
```

According to me this is fetching a static salt, generating a dynamic salt, we're then splitting the given password in 2 parts in an array and adding the static salt in between the two password sections.

We are then hashing the password with `sha12` along with the dynamic salt.

My question to you is, is this more secure or just as secure as the 2 methods I've linked to? Or am I making it more vulnerable by mixing things up this way?

I also take it storing `$password_hash` in a cookie along side a username cookie for automatic login is a big no-no? If so, how do websites remember you through cookies in a secure manner?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `$dynamic_salt` is stored alongside the final `$password_hash` -- since the hash wouldn't be testable without it -- this scheme is quite weak. Using a salt does protect against rainbow tables, but a non-iterated HMAC leaves this scheme weak to brute-force attacks. (The length of the salt does you no good, as it's a known constant in the hash input. Putting it in the middle of the original password doesn't really help either.)

Overall, this scheme is far weaker than `bcrypt()`, as it only (effectively) iterates the hash twice. You're really no better off than if you simply were storing the password using a simpler scheme such as:

```
$salt = uniqid();
$password_hash = hash_hmac('sha512', $password, $salt);
```

But you're still better off using someone else's (tried and tested) password encryption routine, rather than cooking your own.

---

With regard to using the password hash in a cookie -- this is to be avoided, as it allows an attacker with read-only access to the database (*e.g*, via a SQL injection attack or a stolen backup) to impersonate any user in your application without knowing or changing their password. It also means that, if a user's computer has been set to automatically log in, the password hash is stored on it. I'd avoid this.

A better scheme might be to set a randomly generated nonce in a cookie when a user chooses to log in automatically, then store a hash of that nonce in the database. This way, the server can check the correctness of a login key without ever having to "remember" it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll most likely stick to a tried a tested method. As for the cookie situation, I'm a little confused. Surely storing a session token on a users computer, and linking it to an account is still dangerous as this could be faked/guessed/stolen etc? How is this a secure method?

Comment: Any scheme for letting users log in at all will involve, at some point, storing *something* on the user's computer that's linked to their account -- that's unavoidable. What's important here is that you're storing something that's not a critical part of their account (like the password hash), and which isn't derivable from any of the data you directly store in the database.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to increase the level of security with my sites

well, to let you know, no password hashing ussue can increase your site security even a bit.
You have to focus on the other, much more important things such as SQL and file injections, XSS and CSRF vulnerabilities. **If you keep your site secure, it will keep your passwords as well safe just as a side effect.**

Next thing you have to focus on, is **password strength**. **No hash can secure a a silly password** like `joe` or `123`.

As for the hashing itself - you can use whatever you wish, some basic things like using some sane salt like registration time or email and some number of iterations of whatever hashing function is enough. Don't put too much meaning in hashing. it is not the thing that requires SO much attention as inventing some extra-secure original algorithm.

> My question to you is, is this more secure or just as secure as the 2 methods I've linked to? Or am I making it more vulnerable by mixing things up this way?

Dunno if you trust me (I bet you won't) but ALL these methods are secure enough and require no impreovement. And affect no security of the site but only passwords themselves *in case they are stolen using another vulnerability in your site*.

> I also take it storing $password_hash in a cookie along side a username cookie for automatic login is a big no-no?

I don't think it's wise thing to reveal a hash itself. But again, it affects no site security but  passwords *potential* vulnerability only. If your hash and password are strong enough, a logic is making me to say that it is safe enough.

Comment: I also do my best to protect from SQL injections etc (I'll go and rephrase that part) - but thank you for pointing that out for others if they are reading. So there isn't a sure fire "this is the best approach" - pretty much as long as a dynamic and static salt is used, you're pretty good to go? What about the cookie situation?

Comment: the point is not in SQL injections but in the fact that password hashing do not affect your site security.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a reasonable salting scheme, although possibly overkill. It probably doesn't need to be 40 characters long - you're just trying to blow up the size of a rainbow table, not make an unguessable nonce - but making it long won't hurt.

As for autologin, you should store (in a cookie) a random token that corresponds to a database entry pointing to the user's account. When the user changes their password, erase all these entries for that user. When generating this token, `rand()` isn't good enough - you need a *secure*, *unguessable* random number. Unfortunately, PHP doesn't really have a built-in facility for secure random numbers - `mt_rand()` is about as close as it gets, but I personally would directly read random bytes from `/dev/urandom` on a Linux system and use that to generate my nonce.

Answer (score 0):

Salts can be used,but it has got its own limitations. Another way is using bcrypt.More information can be found at http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

And i think This SO article is more than enough [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords/401684#401684)

Comment: That's the same SO article I linked to, my question still stands... is my way more or less secure than what's posted on there and/or on the other article I linked to?